# Need help traversing through associative array PHP and making HTML table

Tags: php, html, html-table, associative-array

```
Array
(
    [total_count] => 10
    [limit] => 1000
    [adminusers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => admin
                    [auth_type] => Local
                    [id] => 1
                    [is_superuser] => 1
                    [groups] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Administrators
                        )

                    [email] => admin@example.com
                )


            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => admin1
                    [auth_type] => Local
                    [id] => 2
                    [is_superuser] => 1
                    [groups] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Administrators
                        )

                    [email] => admin1@example.com
                )
```

I need help getting reading through this. I am confused because there are nested arrays, I'm not sure hot to get into each one. I also need help making a table.

Comment: `there are sub categories like [username] and [admin]` ...well `[username`] just contains a string in each case, and `[admin]` doesn't appear anywhere in your sample data, so TBH it's a bit unclear what the problem is. Maybe show us the code you've tried so far using `foreach` (which is broadly the correct approach) and expain specifically what the issue is in that code. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue, for more guidance. We'll be happy to help once we can clarify precisely what you need and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this. One simple way would be to iterate your array inside the table html. Like that:

**working example with reduced data**

```php
<?php
$arr = [
    "total_count" => 10,
    "adminusers" => [
        [
            "username" => "a",
            "groups" => ["admin"]
        ],
        [
            "username" => "b",
            "groups" => ["guest"]
        ]       
    ],
];


foreach($arr["adminusers"] as $item) {
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>groups</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $item["username"]; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo implode(", ",$item["groups"]); ?></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
 }
?>
```